# Java scripts сложение

Tags: javascript

> var num_first = document.getElementById("one") // *допустим что в "one" ввели 5*
>
> var num_second = document.getElementById("two") // *в "two" ввели 6*
>
> button.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(num_first.value + num_second.value))

после нажатия выводит **56**
вместо **11**

Comment: Надо привести к числу console.log(+num_first.value + +num_second.value)

Comment: @Lenella, https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#сложение-строк-бинарный `console.log(typeof num_first.value)` - строка. Аналогично и `num_second.value`. Таким образом происходит объединение строк.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно использовать функции parseInt или parseFloat для целого и значения с запятой.

```js
var num_first = document.getElementById("one"),
    num_second = document.getElementById("two"),
    button = document.getElementById("count"),
    result = document.getElementById("result")

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let res = 'результат = ' + (parseInt(num_first.value) + parseInt(num_second.value))
  console.log( res )
  result.innerHTML = res
})
```

```html
<input id="one">
<input id="two">
<button id="count">count</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Будьте здоровы, подправил для читаемости код. И вывод в блок result а то добавил а вывод забыл